# WCF Windows Authentication, not being passed

Tags: c#, wcf

In one of my applications I am having issues connecting and authenticating a WCF service via the windows account.  To test this I have moved it into a new solution with a simple console app and the standard WCF start application in VS2010.

WCF Code, for a simple action:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "xxxx\\xxxxxx")]
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
```

The configuration file:

```
 <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"/>
              <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
            </security>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:16674/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="testService.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
```

And the call to this:

```
 testService.Service1Client sv = new testService.Service1Client();
 sv.GetData(1);
```

I'm getting the standard 'Request for principal permission failed.' error although I can't see how the config file is wrong. I've looked at the service object when it is being created and the ClientCredentials.Windows and username objects are null. Can anyone help me out, am I being stupid here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the credentials using code, see this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials.aspx)

```
 testService.Service1Client sv = new testService.Service1Client();
 sv.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
 sv.GetData(1);
```

Comment: I think that article may be out of date but I've found the following

sv.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

but the DefaultNetworkCredentials object is empty?

Comment: I updated the code, have you tried running it ? Do you still get authentication error ? If i remember correctly the credntial only looks empty....

Comment: Still doesn't work and I'm getting the same error, is there any way I can find out which credentials are being used if the object seems empty? Just so I can rule out if it's an AD issue.

Comment: Just looked at your config again, try removing the following line:

<message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>

Since you are not doing message based auth it should not be needed.

Comment: Still no luck, it seems to be trying to pass in an anonymous user having inspected the ServiceSecurityContext property.  I'm hosting this on IIS express which im sure i've configured to disable anon' users.

Comment: Did you enabled Integrated Windows authentication for your endpoint in IIS ?

Comment: I know this is a bit old but, the code has error, how did that fixed the issue?

Comment: The code is 3 yrs old :) it might not work anymore, what are you seeing ?